# Display message box only if cells start with ECH

Tags: vba, loops, if-statement

This is a snip of a larger piece of code--I want it to search the rows of my spreadsheet and display the message box only when the cells in columns R and T both *begin* with ECH.  Currently the code works just fine, but it only displays if the cells value is "ECH".

I've found a couple similar questions on the forum, but wasn't sure how to directly apply them to my situation.  If somebody could recommend how to specify that I want only the cells that begin with "ECH" that'd be great.  Thanks!

```
Dim i As Long
i = 2
Do While Cells(i, "F").Value <> ""
  If Cells(i, "R").Value = "ECH" And Cells(i, "T").Value = "ECH" Then
    MsgBox ("YES")
    Else
    MsgBox ("NO")
  End If
  i = i + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this line:

```
If Cells(i, "R").Value = "ECH" And Cells(i, "T").Value = "ECH" Then
```

like that:

```
If Cells(i, "R").Value Like "ECH*" And Cells(i, "T").Value Like "ECH*" Then
```

---

When using keyword `Like` you can use wildcards in your comparison.

When comparing strings with `=`, they must be exactly the same to return True and you are not allowed to use wildcards. In this case `*` is treated as a normal character.

Comment: Awesome thank you very much! I've tried looking around for a list of those wildcard characters and haven't had much luck.. Do you know where I can find more info on them?